# Accessing an array inside OnKeyListener inner class

Tags: android

I am studying Mobile Application Developer and I am just a beginner. So, forgive me if the question is silly.

I am creating a simple Quiz App. I have `MainActivity` which act as a welcoming screen.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button startBt; //the user will enter this button to go the SecondActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startBt = findViewById(R.id.startBt);
        startBt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, I have a `SecondActivity` which suppose to ask the user a question and get the answer as a String and then increment the score if the answer is correct. There is 10 question. So, I want to use a loop to iterate through all questions. Also, inside the loop there is `OnKeyListener` which indicate when the user press Enter and compare the user answer to the saved answer.

```
        public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

            String[] questions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
            String[] answers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.answers);

            TextView questionTv = findViewById(R.id.questionTv);
            final EditText answerEt = findViewById(R.id.answerPt);
            TextView scoreTv = findViewById(R.id.scoreTv);

            int scoreCounter = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                answerEt.setText("");
                scoreTv.setText(scoreCounter);
                questionTv.setText(questions[i]);

                answerEt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                            if (**answerEt**.getText().toString().equals(**answers[i]**)) {
                                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                t.show();
                                **scoreCounter++;**
                                return true;
                            }
                            else 
                                return false;
                        } else
                            return false;
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

Now, please check the bold part of the code. I cannot access `answerEt, scoreCounter, answer[i]` because they are not final. They should be final because I am working with an inner class. Here is the problem, if I will make them final, I will not have the ability to modify them. However, `scoreCounter` should be incremented to show the user score. Also the *i* should be incremented to iterate through the `answer[]`. One will say "make them Global". Sadly, I tried this and my program crashed. So, How I can solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

pass on responsibility to check for correct answer to a separate function.

```
 private boolean checkAnswer(EditText et, final int questionID) {
    if (et.getText().toString().equals(answers[questionID])) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
        scoreCounter++;
        return true;  // for correct answer.
    }
    return false;  // for incorrect answer.
}
```

Modify your loop to use above function like this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        final int currentQuestionID = i; 
        answerEt.setText("");
        scoreTv.setText(scoreCounter);
        questionTv.setText(questions[i]);

        answerEt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    return checkAnswer((EditText) (v), currentQuestionID);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


    }
```